# mongodb regex how to match image/*

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongoose

I've got a schema like

```
var MediaSchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    user: {
        type: String,
        default: 'whisher',
        trim: true
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    type: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    url: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    }
});
```

in type I can have

image/gif:

image/jpeg:

image/pjpeg:

image/png:

image/svg+xml:

image/example:

but also

application/pdf

video/mpeg

and so on

my goal is fetch all the rows which are images
so I tried with:

```
db.media.find( { type: /image/gif|jpeg|pjpeg|png/i } );
```

but give me

> SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'gif'

so what's the right way ?
Is there a better way of querying without using regex ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator as follows :

```
db.collection.find({type : {$regex : "^image/.*", $options : "i"}})
```

You can also query without using **$regex** operator as follows :

```
db.collection.find({type : /.*image.*/i})
```

Comment: Is there a way without using regex ?

Comment: You're still using a regular expression. It's just a shortcut syntax in the second example.

Answer (score 1):

If this query is frequent, I'd recommend you add a new field that more closely maps to your requirement:

```
isImage : Boolean
```

Or, a bit more general if you'd like:

```
typeGroup: Number
```

You would index either one. `typeGroup` might be set to a `1` for example if it was an image of any type, or `2` if it was a video file, etc.

Performing a regular expression to match the files repeatedly to answer the same question will measurably affect the overall performance of your application. With this alternative approach, you can easily find the correct documents efficiently:

```
Media.find().where('isImage', true).exec(/* your callback */);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.media.find( { type: /image\/gif|jpeg|pjpeg|png/i } );
```

but there is a better way ?

Comment: Yes, I gave a better more efficient approach than using a regex.